# Adding JavaScript ES6 to Dreamweaver CS6

Tags: dreamweaver

How do I make it so that Dreamweaver CS6 doesn't give me a syntax error when I use `let` instead of `var`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Edit > Preferences > Linting then Edit the JS file" is a bogus answer, there is no "linting" option in the preferences of Dreamweaver CS6.  The "linting" feature wasn't added until Creative Cloud.  It is unlikely that there will be a patch, Adobe wants you to switch to a subscription-based version instead.

[Screenshot of Dreamweaver settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcraU.jpg)

Answer (score 7):

Ok, just go to:
Edit > Preferences > Linting
then Edit the **JS** file.

add this property:

```
"esversion" : 6
```

This helped me.

Comment: Yep, that works but is it just fixing the display of the error (problem/warning) in Dreamweaver rather than the underlying issue? Could someone explain whether there's a potential problem with certain clients not being able to run the code because they do not have a browser that supports this ES version?

Comment: This setting is not in CS6, but was introduced in CC versions as [RyanF4's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57574032/2358222) states. Therefore, this answer is incorrect for the question regarding CS6.