# JS Function syntax error with datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am receiving a syntax error. Saying my code may not work until I fix this error but I do not see anything wrong with it. The error line points to this `let weekAgo = new Date();` but that looks right to me. Am I overlooking something? It is also causing the text in my datepicker "from" and "to" to not automatically show up. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The text shows up in [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bobrierton/rq5tazyh/1/) but for some reason not in my application. But the application is throwing that syntax error. So any help would be very nice!

```
<script>
    (function() {
  //move these out since they don't need to 
  const today = new Date();
  let weekAgo = new Date();
  weekAgo.setDate(today.getDate() - 7);
  const $from = $("#StartDate");
  const $to = $("#EndDate");

  $(function() { //DOM-loaded
    //these don't change
    const reportFields = $('#location, #locationbtns, #locationtextarea, #chosendates, #submitbtn, #formattype');
    const employeeFields = $('#employeelist, #employeelistbtns, #employeelisttextarea');
    const loc = $("#loc");
    const EmployeeName = $("#EmployeeName");
    const selectedElement = $('#selected');
    const selected1Element = $('#selected1');
    const reportType = $('#reporttype');
    const generatereportform = $("form[name=generatereport]");
    $(document).click(function(clickEvent) {
      switch (clickEvent.target.id) {
        case 'add':
          setLocationOptionsSelected(true);
          break;
        case 'rem':
          setLocationOptionsSelected(false);
          break;

        case 'add1':
          setSelectedOnEmployeeOptions(true);
          break;
        case 'rem1':
          setSelectedOnEmployeeOptions(false);
          break;
      }
    });
    $(document).change(function(changeEvent) {
      switch (changeEvent.target.id) {
        case 'reporttype':
          handleReportTypeChange();
          break;
        case 'loc':
          handleLocationChange();
          break;
        case 'EmployeeName':
          handleEmployeeNameChange();
          break;
      }
    });

    function handleReportTypeChange() {
      var value = reportType.val();

      if (value === "checklistreports") {
        generatereportform[0].reset();
        reportFields.show();
        loc.prop('required', true);
        employeeFields.show();
        generatereportform.attr("action", "index.cfm?content=reportsassociate");
        EmployeeName.prop('required', true);
      } else if (value === "locationreports") {
        generatereportform[0].reset();
        reportFields.show();
        loc.prop('required', true);
        employeeFields.hide();
        generatereportform.attr("action", "index.cfm?content=reportslocation");
        EmployeeName.prop('required', false);
      } else {
        generatereportform[0].reset();
        reportFields.hide();
        loc.prop('required', false);
        employeeFields.hide();
        generatereportform.attr("action", "#");
        EmployeeName.prop('required', false);
      }

      resetDatePickers();
    }

    function dateSelectHandler(dateText) {
      if (this.id == 'StartDate') {
        $to.datepicker("option", "minDate", dateText);
      } else {
        $from.datepicker("option", "maxDate", dateText);
      }
    }

    function resetDatePickers() {
      let datePickerConfig = {
        changeMonth: true,
        maxDate: today,
        onSelect: dateSelectHandler
      };
      $from.datepicker(datePickerConfig).datepicker('setDate', weekAgo);
      $to.datepicker(Object.assign(datePickerConfig, {
        minDate: weekAgo
      })).datepicker('setDate', today);
    }

    function handleLocationChange() {
      var selected = [];

      loc.find("option:selected").each(function() {
        selected.push($(this).text());
      });

      selectedElement.val(selected.join("\n"));
    }

    function setLocationOptionsSelected(selected) {
      loc.find("option").prop("selected", selected);
      loc.change();
    }


    function setSelectedOnEmployeeOptions(selected) {
      EmployeeName.find("option").prop("selected", selected);
      EmployeeName.change();
    }

    function handleEmployeeNameChange() {
      var selected = [];
      EmployeeName.find("option:selected").each(function() {
        selected.push($(this).text());
      });
      selected1Element.val(selected.join("\n"));
    }
  });

})();
</script>
```

Comment: You mentioned what line the syntax error points to, but what does the syntax error actually say?

Comment: all dreamweaver says is syntax error on that line. "Code hinting may not work until you fix this error."

Comment: `const today = new Date();` what browser are you running on,. `const` is ES6.

Comment: The version of dreamweaver you running is most likely not ES6 aware..

Comment: ie11 is what i have to make it work with

Comment: hmmmm wonder why the dates arent showing up in the fields then

Comment: its crazy that it works in the fiddle though

Comment: The Fiddle is most likely transpiling for you..  Actually on my version of IE11, you fiddle doesn't work either.

Comment: @Keith how should i fix it?

Comment: @Keith you are right. My fiddle was working in chrome but not IE

Comment: If there are no `scope` issues, you could simply replace `const` with `var`,  but a better approach is to look into getting your Javascript compiled, using say webpack & Babel.

Comment: what scope issues are you referring to?

Comment: there complaining about the "let" i think. Would that be var as well?

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] - with the emphasis on **minimal** - looks like your question should have just a single line of code, but there's lots and lots of lines that doesn't seem relevant to the question.

Comment: Yes,.. basically `var` is functionally scoped.  `let` & `const`, will capture scope at assignment.  A quick look at your code, I'd say you would be fine with `var`.  But like I said before, it might be an idea into looking at transpiling your code.

Comment: What version of Dreamweaver are you using? Likely doesn't know about `let` and `const` yet.  Hence the suggestion to change *both* to `var` (`var today = new Date();` etc).

Comment: hmmm it showing the from date but not the to date

Comment: I have the newest dreamweaver

Comment: Also check the rendered JS (in the browser) matches what you have in the designer.

Comment: This might help you dreamweaver bit -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45822265/adding-javascript-es6-to-dreamweaver-cs6

Comment: Hey @Keith I tried that dreamweaver fix it did not work. Just so you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) is not supported by IE 11 <sub>(Or any version for that matter. Refer to the [Browser Compatibilty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Browser_compatibility) section of the MDN documentation)</sub>. A workaround is to merely set that *minDate* property manually:

```
let toDatePickerConfig = datePickerConfig;
toDatePickerConfig.minDate = weekAgo;
$to.datepicker(toDatePickerConfig).datepicker('setDate', today);
```

See a demonstration of this below:

```js
const today = new Date();
let weekAgo = new Date();
weekAgo.setDate(today.getDate() - 7);
$(function() {
  const $from = $("#StartDate");
  const $to = $("#EndDate");

  function dateSelectHandler(dateText) {
    if (this.id == 'StartDate') {
      $to.datepicker("option", "minDate", dateText);
    } else {
      $from.datepicker("option", "maxDate", dateText);
    }
  }
  let datePickerConfig = {
    changeMonth: true,
    maxDate: today,
    onSelect: dateSelectHandler
  };
  $from.datepicker(datePickerConfig).datepicker('setDate', weekAgo);
  let toDatePickerConfig = datePickerConfig;
  toDatePickerConfig.minDate = weekAgo;
  $to.datepicker(toDatePickerConfig).datepicker('setDate', today);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<span class="srch_title" for="StartDate">From:</span>
<input type='text' name="StartDate" id="StartDate" value="" required/>

<span class="srch_title" for="EndDate">To:</span>
<input type='text' name="EndDate" id="EndDate" value="" required/>
```

Comment: wanna take a look at this? https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/176527/js-function-warning-before-closing-browser Im looking for the best way to write this in my environment